# Openshift CRON stopped working

Tags: cron

We have CRON jobs running on our app, all of which were working fine till last night. All the tasks (we have a few in minutely and hourly) have stopped abruptly (the last log entry was for around 1:52 AM IST).

Openshift seems to be running an upgrade since Nov 3, 12:46 EST, so I assume it is because of this but usually any issues during such events subscide within an hour.

We ahve tried the usual steps : Stop/Sart the CRON cartridge, Stop/Start the app, Removed the Cron cartridge and added again but its not working.

Anyone else facing this right now??

Comment: You should ask their support directly. The StackOverflow community typically can't help you with operational issues on public could offerings (and even if they could, any answers would be of little value for the broader internet).

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had to restart the app once more after after re-adding the cartridge. Now its working, although why it occurred is still a mystery.